# how do i read list vertically in python

Tags: python

i have a struggle with my code. so i have a `.txt` file to read and make it to list. so this is my `.txt` file that already made into lists.

```
['0--Parade/0_Parade_marchingband_1_849.jpg']
['1']
['449', '330', '122', '149', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '']
['0--Parade/0_Parade_Parade_0_904.jpg']
['1']
['361', '98', '263', '339', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '']
```

and this is my code to read the `.txt` file

```
import numpy as np
import os

def extract_and_filter_data(splits):
    bb_gt_collection = dict()

    for split in splits:
        with open(
                os.path.join('dataset', 'wider_face_split',
                             '%s.txt' % (split)), 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            line = line.split('\n')[0]
            if line.endswith('.jpg'):
                image_path = os.path.join('dataset', 'WIDER_%s' % (split),
                                          'images', line)
                bb_gt_collection[image_path] = []



            line_components = line.split(' ')
            print(line_components)
```

so, i want to get the number `1` from those lists. but i don't know how to get that value vertically. does anyone can help me? i'm sorry if this a silly question. any answer would be appreciated it. thanks !

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question but would `pandas.read_csv` make the job?

Comment: Files are read line by line, there's no "vertical" access, at least not for text files.  You need to inspect each line and see if it's the value that you want.  That said, a better approach would be to create a list of lists in Python and save it using either the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) modules.  That way you will be able to retrieve your lists as Python objects rather than strings of text.